# How do I get out of this room in Kur?

Tags: axiom-verge

I've just beaten the boss in Kur, and activated the repair drones.  I've made it to the upper right hand room in Kur, but I appear to be stuck there.

[image]

I can't jump high enough to get out of this pit:

[image]

I kind of feel like I'm missing something here.  I've tried shooting everything, drilling, using the glitch gun, my drone, etc.  Nothing seems to get me out of this pit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to go to the right hand side of the pit, and jump and then (in midair) throw the drone out:

[image]

Once you've done this, you get a new item that makes getting out of the pit possible.